# Query Parameter manipulation using Shell

Tags: shell, unix

I am a newbie to shell scripting. Can anyone please help me with this script ?

Question:

Given a url with some query parameters:
Ex: URL: http://xyz.ubs.com/xyzApp.do?lang=fr&fmt=xml&showresults=true&cty=DE"

I have an array of elements with which I want to replace the value of each query parameter in the above URL and make a curl call to get the response from the server. I am successful in making successful curl calls for a single input. I want to do the same for each and every possible combinations

The Vector Array elements I am using are:

Vectors=("\script>alert (0)" '"/ ()' "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" "lasfasf")

I need help to construct the various possible requests using a shell script.

Ex: http://xyz.ubs.com/xyzApp.do?lang='\script>alert (0)'&fmt=xml&showresults=true&cty=DE"
http://xyz.ubs.com/xyzApp.do?lang=fr&fmt='\script>alert (0)'&showresults=true&cty=DE"
http://xyz.ubs.com/xyzApp.do?lang=fr&fmt=xml&showresults='\script>alert (0)'&cty=DE"

and so on..

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it in perl:

```
    if ( @ARGV > 0 ) {
            #print "Number of arguments: " . scalar @ARGV . "\n";
            foreach (@ARGV) {
                    print "$_\n";
            }
            if ( @ARGV > 3 ) {
                    print "Too many arguments! Usage: script.pl arg1 arg2\n";
                    die;
            }
    } else {
            print "No arguments! Usage: script.pl arg1 arg2\n";
            die;
    }

    $arg1 = $ARGV[0];
    $arg2 = $ARGV[1];
```